# How does the Proxy.newProxyInstance first argument class loader work

Tags: java

I was playing with the newProxyInstance and i couldn't wrap my head around how the function worked, and more specifically how the first argument was used.

For example i've tried both:

```
Map map = (Map) Proxy.newProxyInstance(null, new Class[] {Map.class}, handler);
```

and

```
Map map = (Map) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Map.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[] {Map.class}, handler);
```

and they both produce the same results. Now, i would guess that the array of classes is used as a safety check to make sure that the called function is actually supposed to be implemented by the proxy. I am not quite sure though how the first argument, the class loader is used.

Quite new to the language, any insights welcome.

Comment: The `ClassLoader` argument is used to define the generated proxy class. As for the array of interfaces, the generated class literally implements those interfaces. [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) goes into more detail. Though I didn't readily find documentation regarding what it means to pass `null` for the `ClassLoader` argument, but my guess is passing `null` means "use the bootstrap class loader".

Comment: Thanks for the info. One question, what do you mean by "is used to define the generated proxy class". How can that be verified in practice? For example, i've noticed that you can use a random class in the first argument of newProxyInstance and its operation is not affected.

Comment: Every class is loaded by a class loader. This is true even for classes generated at runtime. When you create a proxy instance you are implicitly generating a proxy class (if a matching proxy class doesn't already exist). Thus when you create a proxy instance you have to specify the class loader used to generate the proxy class. You can probably verify this with `proxyInstance.getClass().getClassLoader()`. Note that if the result is null then the bootstrap class loader was used. The bootstrap class loader is the primordial class loader, written in native code.